# Are you always making a concentration check every time you use the Magus' Spells Combat ability and if so what is the DC of the check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

Are you always making a concentration check every time you use the Magus' Spells Combat ability and if so what is the DC of the check?

Answer (score 3):

#### A concentration check isn't *required*, but you probably should be casting defensively if threatened!

When using [spell combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) you don't *always* have to make the concentration check:

> If [a magus] casts this spell defensively, he can decide to take an additional penalty on his attack rolls, up to his Intelligence bonus, and add the same amount as a circumstance bonus on his concentration check.

Casting defensively is what triggers the concentration check… but it also *protects you from attacks of opportunity!* It's not that hard to succeed on the check: You roll d20 + caster level + Int modifier for a magus + any miscellaneous bonuses against DC 15 + double the spell's level. That means, at level 5, you have about a +9 on the check, assuming you didn't grab any traits for concentration. The sorcerer in my game consistently gets results of 30 or more at level 7 with a nearly +20 modifier (+7 from caster level, +6 from Charisma for a sorcerer, and +4 on the check from the feat [Combat Casting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/combat-casting-final/)).

If you *don't* cast defensively, you leave yourself open to attacks of opportunity, and, if enemies hit, the concentration check is more difficult the harder the enemy hits: DC 10 + damage dealt + the spell's level. (And you'll take damage… who wants that?)

Comment: There is a balance between high AC and high concentration DC that sometimes makes it easier to risk taking an attack.

Comment: I dunno. From my experience, assuming you have decent spellcasting stat, and a background trait/feat for concentration I feel like the concentration check is always safer and easier to your favor. You have a DC 22 for a 6th level spell. (The highest a magus can cast) at lv 10 they are at a DC 18 for their 4th level spell. and they already have a ~+15 w.o traits or feats. Having Combat Casting makes it impossible to fail. When the magus gets 5th level they are rolling +18 against a DC 20 w.o spell combat. Even if they have super high ac, there is a 5% chance the enemy will roll a 20 and crit.